# Issue with custom log routing with ECS fargate, Firelense and fluentbit to cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, fluent-bit

I am trying to get logs from my app container to cloudwatch using firelesne and fluentbit by aws, and not getting it.
Application writes log on `/opt/app/log/*.log`
here is my task definition and fluentbit config file.

`

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "batching_task" {
  family = "${var.project}-${var.environment}-node1"

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
      {
      essential = true
      image = "fluent-bit image"
      repositoryCredentials = {
        credentialsParameter = var.docker_login
      }
    name = "log_router"
    firelensConfiguration = {
    type = "fluentbit"
        options={
          enable-ecs-log-metadata ="false"
          config-file-type = "file"
          config-file-value = "/fluent-bit.conf"
            }  
    }
    logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs"
        options = {
          awslogs-group = "/ecs/app-${var.environment}"
          awslogs-region = "us-east-1"
          awslogs-create-group = "true"
          awslogs-stream-prefix= "firelens"
                }
            }
      mountPoints = [
                {
    "containerPath" : "/opt/app/log/",
    "sourceVolume" : "var-log"
                }
            ]
    memoryReservation = 50
    },    
     
    {
      name  = "node"
      image = "app from private docker registry"
      repositoryCredentials = {
        credentialsParameter = var.docker_login
      }
      essential = true
      mountPoints = [
                {
    "containerPath" : "/opt/app/log/",
    "sourceVolume" : "var-log"
                }
            ]
      environment = [
        {
          name  = "APP_PORT"
          value = "80"
      ]
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 80
          hostPort      = 80
          protocol      = "tcp"
        }
      ]
       logConfiguration = {
    logDriver = "awsfirelens"
    options = {
        Name = "cloudwatch"
            region = "us-east-1"
            enable-ecs-log-metadata = "false"
            log_group_name = "/ecs/app"
        auto_create_group = "true"
        log_stream_name = "$(ecs_task_id)"
            retry_limit = "2"
          }
       }
       dependsOn = [
        {
          "containerName": "log_router",
          "condition": "START"
        }
      ]
     }
  ])
  volume  { 
    name = "var-log"
     } 
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.app.arn 
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.app.arn
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = var.fargate_cpu
  memory                   = var.fargate_memory
}
```

`

Dockerfile from where Fluentbit image is created

`

```
FROM amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:latest
ADD fluent-bit.conf /fluent-bit.conf
ADD test.log /test.log
ENV AWS_REGION=us-east-1

ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID # you could give this a default value as well
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY # you could give this a default value as well
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

RUN mkdir ~/.aws && cd ~/.aws && touch credentials 

RUN echo -e '\
[default]\n\ 
$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID\n\ 
$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY\ 
' > ~/.aws/credentials
```

`

Fluent-bit.conf

`

```
[SERVICE]

    Flush 5
    Deamon off

[INPUT]
    # test log
    Name tail
    Path /opt/app/log/test.log
    Tag test

[OUTPUT]
    # test log
    Name cloudwatch_logs
    Match test*
    region us-east-1
    log_group_name /ecs/app
    log_stream_name app-$(ecs_task_id)
    auto_create_group true
    log_retention_days 90
```

`

I have been following this docs

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-firelens-under-the-hood/tree/9ecd26e02cb5e13bb5c312c651a3ac601f7f42cd/fluent-bit-log-pipeline

https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/1.0/configuration/file

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-firelens-examples/blob/mainline/examples/fluent-bit/ecs-log-collection/task-definition-tail.json

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/firelens-example-taskdefs.html

I have two log streams created which are part of task-definition and it only forwards stdout logs I need app logs which are not being forwarded.

log streams which are part of fluent-bit config are not created
Que: 1) how does my log router sidecar container reads log from the app containers filesystem, do I have to set anything for that?
2) is my configuration file okay does it need anything else?
3) what m I missing?